# Орфография и грамматика

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые филологи, помогите математику расставить знаки препинания в абзаце учебного пособия. Вот текст:
"Кроме определения оптимального объема выпускаемой продукции у руководителя может возникнуть вопрос, каким образом отразится на прибыли:

– увеличение каждого из потребляемых ресурсов;  
  – совершенствование каждого технологического процесса; 
  – изменение стоимости сырья;  
  – использование какого-либо нового ресурса и т.д."

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, оборот с "кроме" -выделительный, ставим запятую. Во-вторых,я бы не ставила двоеточие и перед пунктами тире, если уж выделять их,то  с помощью большой точки.

Кроме определения оптимального объема выпускаемой продукции, у руководителя может возникнуть вопрос, каким образом отразится на прибыли

. увеличение каждого из потребляемых ресурсов

. совершенствование каждого технологического процесса

. изменение стоимости сырья

.  использование какого-либо нового ресурса и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Да, собственно, у Вас все правильно. Честно говоря, сомневаюсь, стоит ли после перечисления пунктов ставить вопросительный знак. А в остальном ошибок не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Правила русского языка не настолько изменились. Поэтому перед списком НУЖНО поставить двоеточие, а его элементы друг от друга отделять запятой или точкой с запятой. "Буллеты" (что точки, что дефисы) не грамматическое явление, а оформительское, к правописанию отношения не имеет.

Comment: А где Вы ТАКОЕ правило нашли? Двоеточие ставится перед однородными членами ПОСЛЕ ОБОБЩАЮЩЕГО слова,а его здесь нет. Перед списком может ставиться в протоколах, в канцелярском стиле, а здесь научный, не канцелярский, значит, двоеточия нет.

Comment: С точки зрения Розенталя, как раз в научной речи (как и в деловой, которую можно назвать также канцелярской) двоеточие ставится.
Сейчас попробую найти электронный вариант, чтобы руками абзац не переписывать.
Upd
Нашла тут: http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxii.html#sect89
(п.1, абзац в конце).
Кстати, я вот думаю, а не должен ли глагол быть во множественном числе - "как отразЯтся..."